# Mapping values from vector to the data frame: Calculating percentile

Tags: r, function, loops, vector, percentile

I have a vector of numbers (**nth_RT**) and a data frame (**df**):

```
nth_RT 
[1] 0.61 0.47 0.50 0.53 0.50 0.56


df
#    Subject    RT Trial Block  Rank
#     (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
#1        1   234     1     1     1
#2        1   239     3     1     2
#3        1   563     2     1     3
#4        1   230     1     2     1
#5        1   234     3     2     2
#6        1   467     2     2     3
#7        1   111     3     3     1
#8        1   466     2     3     2
#9        1   543     1     3     3
#10       2    44     2     1     1
#11       2   223     3     1     2
#12       2   343     1     1     3
#13       2    34     2     2     1
#14       2   242     3     2     2
#15       2   324     1     2     3
#16       2    54     1     3     1
#17       2   345     3     3     2
#18       2   656     2     3     3
```

I want to calculate and add as a new column (**nth**) the nth percentile for each block per subject, i.e., 61st pecentile of the RTs for the 1st block 1st subject, 47th pecentile of the RTs for the 2nd block 1st subject, 50th percentile of the RTs for the 3rd block 1st subject, 53rd percentile of the 1st block 2nd participant, etc. So the data frame would look like this:

```
df
#    Subject    RT Trial Block  Rank  nth
#1        1   234     1     1     1   310.28
#2        1   239     3     1     2   310.28
#3        1   563     2     1     3   310.28
#4        1   230     1     2     1   233.76
#5        1   234     3     2     2   233.76
#6        1   467     2     2     3   233.76
#7        1   111     3     3     1   466
#8        1   466     2     3     2   466
#9        1   543     1     3     3   466
#10       2    44     2     1     1   230.2
#11       2   223     3     1     2   230.2
#12       2   343     1     1     3   230.2
#13       2    34     2     2     1   242
#14       2   242     3     2     2   242
#15       2   324     1     2     3   242
#16       2    54     1     3     1   382.32
#17       2   345     3     3     2   382.32
#18       2   656     2     3     3   382.32
```

I have a code for one block per participant but it doesn't work:

```
nth_RT <-quantile(df$RT ~ Block * Subject, nth_RT[1])
```

Is there a better way of calculating the percentiles and adding them as a new column? I guess one could use a loop or a function to read in successively each value from a vector and then calculate the percentiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the vector `nth_RT` does not have a clear correspondence to your `Block` and `Subject` in `df`. So I suggest you should create a matrix or data.frame to show the correspondence clearly. For example,

```
grid <- expand.grid(Block = unique(df$Block), Subject = unique(df$Subject))
grid_nth_RT <- cbind(grid, nth_RT)
```

Then you will get:

```
> grid_nth_RT
  Block Subject nth_RT
1     1       1   0.61
2     2       1   0.47
3     3       1   0.50
4     1       2   0.53
5     2       2   0.50
6     3       2   0.56
```

Then, we can use a for loop to go through each `Block`-`Subject` pair.

```
df$nth <- array(0, nrow(df))
for(i in 1:nrow(grid_nth_RT)) {
  index <- df$Block == grid_nth_RT[i,"Block"] &
           df$Subject == grid_nth_RT[i,"Subject"]
  df$nth[index] <- quantile(df[index,"RT"], grid_nth_RT[i,"nth_RT"])
}
```

We find the `index` of all the rows for the ith `Block`-`Subject`. Then we can subset `df[index,"RT"]`. We compute the quantile of the `df[index,"RT"]` at percentage `grid_nth_RT[i,"nth_RT"]`. We store the result to `df$nth[index]`.

```
> df
   Subject  RT Trial Block Rank    nth
1        1 234     1     1    1 310.28
2        1 239     3     1    2 310.28
3        1 563     2     1    3 310.28
4        1 230     1     2    1 233.76
5        1 234     3     2    2 233.76
6        1 467     2     2    3 233.76
7        1 111     3     3    1 466.00
8        1 466     2     3    2 466.00
9        1 543     1     3    3 466.00
10       2  44     2     1    1 230.20
11       2 223     3     1    2 230.20
12       2 343     1     1    3 230.20
13       2  34     2     2    1 242.00
14       2 242     3     2    2 242.00
15       2 324     1     2    3 242.00
16       2  54     1     3    1 382.32
17       2 345     3     3    2 382.32
18       2 656     2     3    3 382.32
```

By the way, from your code

```
quantile(df$RT ~ Block * Subject, nth_RT[1])
```

I think you have some misunderstanding on `~`. Things with `~` are called `formula` in R. You may check out this page 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html
to learn more about `formula` in R.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer! it worked perfectly. indeed, I guess I should definitely check some infos on formulas.